# How to print the entire array list without appending the index in Java?

Tags: java

I'm a rookie in Java. I just started it a day before. I don't know whether its a stupid question. Whatever , when i run the below codes , I got

[I@15db9742 as output.

```
public class array1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        int[] arr={1,2,3};
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

what does it mean ? 
 When i create a char array as

```
char[] c={'a','b','c'};
```

i got the output as  `abc`

```
System.out.println(c);
```

Why i didn't get the o/p as `123` in the above case...
  Eager to hear the answer...................

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the array object directly. Hence you are seeing the String representation of object and not its content. Probably you want to do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm getting an error i.e Arrays cannot be resolved.

Comment: You ned to import Array class. `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: Thanks man . I forgot to import the java.util.Arrays package.

Comment: why it brings the output within the square bracket as [1,2,3]. How to remove those brackets ?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the array wrongly..
do either

```
int[] arr={1,2,3};
         for (int i : arr) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }
```

or print it using the Arrays class

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));`

Comment: I got the o/p as [1, 2, 3]. But how to remove those square brackets?

Comment: then do the for loop... because the [ ... ] are to indicate that it is an array

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment. You want to print the content:

```
for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){

System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```